# What is wrong with my solution to find the size of an angle of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

The sides of a triangle $a$, $b$, and $c$ has the following lengths.

$$a=x^2+x+1$$

$$b=2x+1$$

$$c=x^2-1$$

Since $a,b,c>0$, $x>1$.

$$a-b=x(x-1)>0\ (\because x>1)$$

$$a-c=x+2>0$$

Therefore, $a$ is the longest side, and its opposite angle $A$ is the largest angle. Let $B$ and $C$ be the opposite angle of $b$ and $c$, respectively.

$$a:b:c=x^2+x+1:2x+1:x^2-1=A:B:C$$

$$A=(x^2+x+1)k$$

$$B=(2x+1)k$$

$$C=(x^2-1)k$$

$$A+B+C=(2x^2+3x+1)k=\pi$$

$$k=\frac{\pi}{2x^2+3x+1}$$

$$A=\frac{(x^2+x+1)\pi}{2x^2+3x+1}$$

The correct value of A is $\frac{2}{3}\pi$, but the given solution doesn't produce the right answer. I got the correct value by an alternative method, but I can't figure out what's wrong with the solution above.

Comment: $a:b:c = \sin A : \sin B : \sin C$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the angles A,B,C are not "proportional" as you wrote.

By the [cosine law](https://Well,%20the%20angles%20A,B,C%20are%20not%20%22proportional%22%20as%20you%20wrote.%20Do%20know%20the%20cosine%20law?), you have
$$
a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc \cos(A).
$$
Hence
$$
\cos(A)=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}=\frac{(2x+1)^2+(x^2-1)^2-(x^2+x+1)^2}{2(2x+1)(x^2-1)}=-\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Therefore $A=\frac{2}{3}\pi$.

Comment: +1. To the proposer: The sides are proportional to the $sines$ of the angles: $(\sin A)/a=(\sin B)/b=(\sin C)/c.$